# How to allow view to expand without pushing othe views off screen

Tags: android

I have a horizontal layout with two views in it: an `EditText` that will show a chosen path, and a "Browse" `Button` to the right of the `EditText`.

I want the `EditText` to expand as required, but not to the extent that it pushes the `Button` off the screen.

Here is my current xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/path_view">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/folder_edittext"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:hint="Folder"/>


    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/browse_button"
            android:text="..."
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried all types of layout, I have tried using `toLeftOf`, `toRightOf` and everything I can think of, I think I now need help if I am to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [layout weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/path_view">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:id="@+id/folder_edittext"
              android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:hint="Folder"/>

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/browse_button"
            android:text="..."
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This xml can be interpreted as saying: "let the `EditText` take up all the horizontal room that is not filled by other views" (in this case, the only other view is the `Button`).

Comment: Brilliant. Both of your solutions work. thanks.

Many thanks.

Comment: @SmokeTester You are welcome. Since you're relatively new here, I will point you to these guidelines on how to most appropriately indicate that you found an answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try with `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/path_view">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/folder_edittext"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="Folder"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/browse_button" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/browse_button"
        android:text="..."
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```